# Python: creating a loop with an integer converted to a string

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm brand new to Python as of a few weeks ago for a class I am taking. I am currently writing a program that is designed to take a four digit integer, take the absolute differences of each number, and then sum them. Meaning, you enter a four digit PIN, the program takes the absolute values of (number 1- number 2), (2-3), and (3-4) and then sums them and prints the sum.

I am supposed to write a for loop in order to do this after converting the integer to a string.

I was told to structure the loop using  for char in value:  but I am confused as to how to set this up. I understand basic slicing, and I assume I need to use that in my answer. 
This is what I have so far for my code:

```
def main():
    print("This program is designed to determine the weight of a four-digit PIN by calculating the sum of the absolute difference between each digit.")
    # Prompt user for PIN
    x = input("Enter your PIN: ")
    # Call the weight function providing the four digit pin as an argument
    weight(x)


# Weight function
def weight(x):
    # Convert integer to string
    str(x)
    # Initialize variables
    a, b, c, d = x
# Setup for a loop that uses digits as sequence, sum differences between each digit in integer
# Print sum
```

The loop is the part that is messing me up. I know there’s other ways to solve this without using a loop, but for my assignment I am supposed to.

Comment: You're converting the variable x to string, but you're not storing it back into x. Try x = str(x)

Comment: `a,b,c,d=str(x)` no need to store `x` again if you aren't using it

Answer (score 1):

> I was told to structure the loop using `for char in value:` but I am confused as to how to set this up.

The way you are assigning `x` with `x = input("Enter your PIN: ")`, `x` is already a string. The `for` loop should be used to convert each character to an integer before returning the weighted sum. Here is one way using a list to store the integers:

```
def weight(value):
    int_values = []  # Create an empty list to store the integers.
    for char in value:
        int_values.append(int(char))  # Converts char to int and adds to list.
    return abs(int_values[0] - int_values[1]) + abs(int_values[1] - int_values[2]) + abs(int_values[2] - int_values[3])


pin = ''
while len(pin) != 4 or not pin.isdigit():  # Make sure PIN is 4 digits.
    pin = input("Enter your PIN: ")
pin_weight = weight(pin)
print('Weight of {} is {}'.format(pin, pin_weight))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're converting `x` to a string but not storing the return value of the `str(x)` call. You can fix this by storing the value of `str(x)` in the `x` variable.

```
def weight(x):
    x = str(x)
    a, b, c, d = x
    # continue with loop
```

You can clean this up a little bit by storing the return value of `str(x)` straight into `a, b, c, d`

```
def weight(x):
    a, b, c, d = str(x)
    # continue with loop
```

The final option that I think you should consider trying out is looping through the digits in the pin without storing them in the variables `a, b, c, d`. To get you started, you can try this out:

```
# PIN = 8273
def weight(x):
    for i in range(len(str(x))): # loop through indices in x
        print(x[i]) # prints 8, 2, 7, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

some may want to avoid mixing `str` operations in a numerical formula

```
num = 1234

digits = []
for _ in range(4):
    num, rem = divmod(num, 10)
    digits.append(rem)

digits
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

breaks up the number into a list of the 4 digits - the reverse order dosen't matter for your weight calc